# append specific parent node programatically and add node to specific location

Tags: c#, xml

This is my sample xml
[image]

I am finding EmpNo throug linq query like

```
var doc = XDocument.Parse(fileContent);
var articleValueFromXML =
from item in doc.Elements("MainHeader").Elements("EmpDetail").Elements("Details").Elements("Department").Elements("Unit")   
 where (string) item.Element("EmpNo") == "4444"
 select item;
```

Now i want to append node above tag `Details` called `<Skills>.Net</skills>`

There will be multiple EmpDetail node. I want to add node above Details and below EmpDetail  node if i find EmpNo. How i do this?

Comment: Try this : var articleValueFromXML = doc.Descendants("EmpDetail").Where(item => (string)item.Descendants("EmpNo") == "4444").ToList();

Comment: Following will extract all data : var articleValueFromXML = doc.Descendants("EmpDetail").Where(item => (string)item.Descendants("EmpNo") == "4444").Select(x => new {
   age = (int)x.Element("Age"),
   weight = (int)x.Element("weight"),
   sal = (int)x.Descendants("Sal").FirstOrDefault()
}).List();

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is not difficult.

You are writing way too much code.

Read the [helpful documentation on MSDN regarding LINQ to XML](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/concepts/linq/linq-to-xml-overview).

You want something like this:

```
var details =
    from detail in xml.Descendants("EmpDetail")
    where detail.Descendants("EmpNo").FirstOrDefault()?.Value == "4444"
    select detail;

foreach (var detail in details)
{
    detail.Add(new XElement("Skills", "C#"));
}
```

Comment: what is alternative for FirsOrDefault in c# 5.0?

Comment: C# 5.0 has first or default. Anyway you should upgrade to 7.1

Comment: its appending node below closing tag of Details. I want to insert above the start of Details tag

Comment: @Happy the wording of your question was unclear as to which details tag you meant. But it should be easy for you to adapt the solution by querying for the parent tag one level up. If you still have trouble with that you need to edit your question to make it clear what you mean because the behavior you described is the behavior exhibited by this answer.

Comment: i thought my question was clear on to where exactly i want to add node. May be wording can be wrong but description was clear

Comment: If possible answer this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48024797/add-multiple-node-inside-parent-node-created-on-fly

Comment: You have `detail` and `empDetail`. This code makes `skills` a child of `empDetail` and a sibling of `detail`. Unless you introduce another level hierarchy of nesting, what else do you expect?